# Dismiss keyboard as well as fire button's touchupinside event using IQKeyboardManager

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using this code in appdelegate

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().touchResignedGestureIgnoreClasses = [UINavigationBar.self,UIControl.self]
```

assigning **touchResignedGestureIgnoreClasses** property is allowing me to fire the UIButton event if keyboard is open but it does not dismisses the keyboard simultaneously.

Comment: IQKeyboardManager wont dismiss the keyboard if you are performing any actions through controls which are included in  the **touchResignedGestureIgnoreClasses**, so as you have included your UIButton

Comment: @Jayachandra A what should i do then .. if i skip UIbutton from this property , it just dismisses the keyboard the event don't get fired

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line of code inside your function that handles button's event:

`self.view.endEditing = true`

Comment: Yes i can use this , but for this i have add this line in each controller . But i want a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

In such specific cases you might required to create your own button class sub-classing **UIButton** and observe the events inside it. Later then specify UIButtons custom class as your own button which you have created.

```
class KOButton: UIButton {

    var isKeyBoardOpened = false

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code

        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "highlighted", options: .new, context: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardOpened), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "highlighted" {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
            self.isKeyBoardOpened = false
        }
    }

    func keyboardOpened() {
        isKeyBoardOpened = true;
    }


}
```

[image: Storyboard changes]

I hope this might helps you, if it did't work the follow the another approach below mentioned

Write an extension for **UIViewController**

```
// Declare a global var to produce a unique address as the assoc object handle
private var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0
extension UIViewController{

    var isKeyBoardOpened: Bool {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle) as! Bool
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }


    func addKBOforButton(aButton: UIButton) {
        aButton.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "highlighted", options: .new, context: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardOpened), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    }

    override open func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "highlighted" {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
            self.isKeyBoardOpened = false
        }
    }

    func keyboardOpened() {
        isKeyBoardOpened = true;
    }
}
```

And then call this function from your viewcontroller

```
self.addKBOForButton(aButton: button)
```

Comment: can i declare these functions in ViewController extension instead of uibutton class and call it in viewdidload so that every controller inherits this functionality ??

Comment: @PreetiRani i'm editing my answer, please have a look

Comment: getting this error     ----->                                                                   An instance 0x7fea88ccd6b0 of class UIButton was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x60000042e6c0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60000064b640: Observer: 0x7fea88ccaa20, Key path: highlighted, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x6000006427f0>